# How can I create a SaveButton which returns to me to a special URL

Tags: admin-on-rest

I know that I can use an url as redirect parameter for an SaveButton like this:

```
const ResourcePropertyEditToolbar = props => <Toolbar {...props} >
    <SaveButton />
    <SaveButton label="save and resource" redirect={"/resource/21"} 
                submitOnEnter={false} raised={false} />
</Toolbar>;
```

As you see the "/resource/21" is hard coded and it works (for this entry ;-) How can I dynamically create the url? The value itself is included in the current data set which is edited, like this:

```
export const ResourcePropertyEdit = (props) => (
<Edit {...props} >
    <SimpleForm toolbar={<ResourcePropertyEditToolbar />}>
        <NumberInput source="position" defaultValue="1"/>
        <TextInput source="property_name" validate={required}/>
        <ReferenceInput label="Resource" source="fk_resource" 
                        reference="resource">
            <AutocompleteInput optionText="shortname"/>
         </ReferenceInput>
    </SimpleForm>
</Edit>
);
```

It is the value of the selected fk_resource.

Here is the code snippet for the base Form with the ReferenceManyField Entry, the target is to jump back to this view after editing a resource_property.

```
export const ResourceEdit = (props) => (
<Edit {...props}>
    <SimpleForm>
        <TextInput source="shortname" validate={required}/>
        <ReferenceManyField target="fk_resource"
                            reference="resource_property" >
            <Datagrid>
                <NumberField source="position"/>
                <TextField source="property_name"/>
                <ReferenceField label="Property" source="fk_property" reference="property" allowEmpty>
                    <TextField source="shortname"/>
                </ReferenceField>
                <EditButton/>
            </Datagrid>
        </ReferenceManyField>
    </SimpleForm>
</Edit>
);
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

The current data set is called the record in AOR. If the URL is in the record you can access it simply by

```
const ResourcePropertyEditToolbar = props => <Toolbar {...props} >
    <SaveButton />
    <SaveButton label="save and resource" redirect={props.record.url ? props.record.url : null}
                submitOnEnter={false} raised={false} />
</Toolbar>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I receive "Cannot read property 'url' of undefined" inspect my props I have only {"invalid":false, "submitonenter": true}.

Comment: Does your record have the URL in it?

Comment: Made a change above, check if this works. I too am a bit unclear about how AOR behaves when moving between pages.

Comment: I have added the source form with the ReferenceManyField entry, which should be the target for the Save button. Existing URLs point to current resource_property entries only. My props have the fields invalid and submitonenter only.

Comment: Inside a view actions, the `record` is named `data`. You can see a working example in the demo app: https://github.com/marmelab/admin-on-rest-demo/blob/master/src/reviews/ReviewEditActions.js

Comment: This does not work because SimpleForm only passes 3 props to toolbar (handleSubmitWithRedirect, invalid, submitOnEnter) so record is not available. I was able to make this work by hacking SimpleForm.js to also include the "record" property. 
i.e. 

{toolbar &&
          React.cloneElement(toolbar, {
            handleSubmitWithRedirect: this.handleSubmitWithRedirect,
            invalid,
            submitOnEnter,
            >>>> record <<<<,
          })}